# How do I stop background audio from playing through the receiver while using AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudiosession

My app records audio but I also want it to play what ever background music is playing from other apps eg Spotify.

```
                                             //play and record 
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: audioSessionCategory 
 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:NULL];
```

This allows the music to play but it routes the background music to the receiver when ever I open the app. Is there a way to force it to use the speaker or headphone port if something is plugged in. Much like AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker but allowing background audio to continue playing?

--
Edit:
I was currently setting `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement` if I change it to 
`AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat` then it will default to speaker but this optimises the audio for videochat and I want an unprocessed signal

Also if I use  `overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:NULL]` this works but this stops the background music from playing when I open the app.

--